# ejabberd 14.12 xml rpc enable

Tags: linux, xml, rpc, ejabberd

I've got problem with my new ejabberd installation. I need to enable mod xml_rpc, so what I do:

```
I'm uncomment this in my ejabberd.yml file:
 ## To handle XML-RPC requests that provide admin credentials:
  ##
  ##  -
  ##   port: 4560
  ##   module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
```

So it's look now like this

```
 ## To handle XML-RPC requests that provide admin credentials:
  ##
    -
     port: 4560
     module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
```

But in my logs i got these errors and ejabberd won't work.

```
2015-02-12 17:16:33.180 [error] <0.37.0>@ejabberd_config:get_plain_terms_file:176 Cannot load /opt/ejabberd-14.12/conf/ejabberd.yml: Syntax error on line 149 at position 5: did not find expected key
2015-02-12 17:18:58.635 [error] <0.37.0>@ejabberd_config:get_plain_terms_file:176 Cannot load /opt/ejabberd-14.12/conf/ejabberd.yml: Syntax error on line 149 at position 5: did not find expected key
```

Can someone help me how i can enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces before each uncommented line, it worked for me.

Comment: [Markup languages and indentation](http://fdik.org/yml/)